# Probability puzzle - Two people drawing marbles... what is the probability one will be the first to get a certain color

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics

One of my relatives had a probability question that they asked me that was a little puzzling...  What do you think?  Can anyone explain how to do a problem like this?

A container has six yellow marbles and nine black marbles.  Ruth and Dave each start taking a marble.  They choose these marbles at random and Ruth was the first to draw a marble.  If they do not replace any of the marbles, until one of them get's a yellow marble.  What is the probability that Dave will be the one to draw the yellow marble.

If anyone could explain how to do a problem like this, that would be great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Start by ignoring the fact that there are two people drawing marbles; just consider the sequence in which the marbles are drawn.

Further, note that we only care what happens until we get the first yellow marble drawn.  Let $\tau$ be the number of the draw in which that happens.

Then every marble you draw before time $\tau$ will be black!  If you know that the first $t$ marbles are black, what is the probability that the $(t+1)$st marble will be yellow? You can use this to figure out, using the conditional probability formula, the probability distribution of the random time $\tau$ at which the first yellow marble is drawn. (Because for instance, $P(\tau=5)$ is the probability that the marbles drawn are black, black, black, black, yellow; what is the probability that this happens?)

Once you know $P(\tau=t)$ for each $t\in\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$ (why does it only need to go up to $10$?), you need only consider
$$
P(\tau\text{ is even})=P(\tau=2)+P(\tau=4)+\cdots+P(\tau=10)
$$
and
$$
P(\tau\text{ is odd})=P(\tau=1)+P(\tau=3)+\cdots+P(\tau=9).
$$

**Update:**

To compute $P(\tau=t)$, note that $\tau=t$ is precisely the event that the first $t-1$ balls drawn are black and the $t$ ball drawn is yellow.  There are a few different ways that you can think about this, but here's one:

Consider drawing ALL of the balls, in sequence.  The sequences of draws that we are interested in counting consist of $t-1$ black marbles, followed by a yellow marble, followed by any arrangement of the remaining $9-(t-1)=10-t$ black marbles and $5$ yellow marbles. (So, the number of such sequences is precisely the number of ways to choose that last substring.)

Once you've found the number of such sequences, note that
$$
P(\tau=t)=\frac{\text{# of such sequences}}{\text{total # of sequences}}=\frac{\text{# of such sequences}}{\binom{15}{9}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  So, if the total number of marbles is 15, then the number of permutations is 15!.  However, since I have 6 yellow and 9 black, then the number of distinguishable permutations is 15!/(6!*9!).   How do I get the next step to determine P(t=5).

Comment: @Tim2376 You've pretty much completely ignored my hint! The probability that $\tau=t$, for any $t$, is the probability that the first $t-1$ marbles are all black and marble $t$ is yellow. On the first draw, the probability of getting black is $\frac{9}{15}$. __Conditioned__ on this having happened, the probability that the second is black is $\frac{8}{14}$. And so on, and so on.  Can you see how to take it from there?

Comment: Alternatively, you want to count the number of permutations of the multiset $\{B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y\}$ such that the first $t-1$ symbols are $B$ and the $t$th symbol is $Y$. This can be done by arranging the remaining $9-(t-1)$ $B$'s and $5$ $Y$'s in any way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.  I guess I am just a little confused... I am trying to follow your hints.  Here is what I am puzzled about... If I take P(even) = (8/14) + (6/12) + (4/10) + (2/8) + (0/6) = 1.72 and P(odd) = (9/15) + (7/13) + (5/11) + (3/9) + (1/7) = 2.07 it seems like I am ending up with a probability greater then 1.  I don't know that much at all about probability... Do you see where I am going wrong?  Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tim2376 Take a look at the update.

Comment: So, is the probability that Dave will be the one to draw the yellow marble is 0.378?

Comment: I get $271/715$, which is $\approx 0.379$.  But that seems like rounding error.

Comment: Alright.  Thank you so much for the help!  I have learned so much.  I appreciate you explaining all this.